# Using interceptors with react-query

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor, react-query

I have a bunch of custom `react-query` hooks in my app, e.g.:

```
export const useItems = () => {
  return useQuery(["items"], async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/api/items");

    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw response.data.error ?? "Unknown error";
    }

    return response.data;
  });
}

export const useVenueSearch = (placeId) => {
  return useQuery(["places", placeId], async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/places/${placeId}`);

    if (response.status !== 200 && response.status !== 404) {
      throw response.data.error ?? "Unknown error";
    }

    return response.data;
  });
}

...
```

At any point in time, in any of these custom hooks API calls, the server may decide that the user needs to accept the new Terms and Conditions in order to continue using the product. The server returns a known 4xx response in this case.

What's the best way to centrally handle this 4xx response and update React's state (to show a modal asking the user to accept the Terms and Conditions)?

---

##### Bonus question (similar scenario)

Given a bunch of custom **mutation** hooks, I'd like to introduce an artificial delay so requests never finish before 1000ms passed. What would be a good central place to put this logic?

Comment: Why are you checking the response status? Axios rejects the promise for unsuccessful requests

Comment: _"What's the best way"_... this is way too broad a question for StackOverflow. Attempting to answer it would also involve detailed knowledge of your application (state stores, modals, etc) that you have not provided

Comment: Status is checked because in my app I have the axios `validateStatus` defined as `status >= 200 && status < 500`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the interceptor provided by axios and u can even use the retry method of it to hit the API again.

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

you can read more about it here. https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors
but apart from this you need to create your own wrapper which will do this part but react-query didn't provide interceptor.